# Erro ao salvar registro com herança com Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, herança

Eu tenho uma classe Person, implementada da seguinte maneira:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person extends Model{

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String docIdentification;

    private String phone;

    private String email;

    private String contactName;

}
```

E uma classe Supplier que extends dessa Person, implementada da seguinte maneira:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "supplier")
@Entity
public class Supplier extends Person {
    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Location location;

    private String website;

    private String observation;
}
```

Ao realizar um post o seguinte código é executado no service:

```
 @Override
    public SupplierDTO create(SupplierForm supplierForm) {
        if(repository.existsByName(supplierForm.getName()))
            throw new SupplierAlreadyExistWithNameException();


        Location location = new Location();
        if(supplierForm.getLocation() != null){
            location = locationService.createLocation(
                    Location
                    .builder()
                        .latitude(supplierForm.getLocation().getLatitude())
                        .longitude(supplierForm.getLocation().getLongitude())
                        .address(supplierForm.getLocation().getAddress())
                        .city(supplierForm.getLocation().getCity())
                        .state(supplierForm.getLocation().getState())
                    .build()
            );
        }


        List<Person> byNameIgnoreCase = personRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(supplierForm.getName());
        Supplier supplier = new Supplier();
        if(!byNameIgnoreCase.isEmpty()){
            supplier.setId(byNameIgnoreCase.get(0).getId());
        }

        //person
        supplier.setName(supplierForm.getName());
        supplier.setPhone(supplierForm.getPhone());
        supplier.setEmail(supplierForm.getEmail());
        supplier.setContactName(supplierForm.getContactName());
        supplier.setDocIdentification(supplierForm.getDocIdentification());

        //Supplier
        supplier.setCreatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
        supplier.setUpdatedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
        supplier.setLocation(location);
        supplier.setWebsite(supplierForm.getWebsite());
        supplier.setObservation(supplierForm.getObservation());

        return new SupplierDTO(repository.save(supplier));
    }
```

No meu banco, o campo "nome" da tabela "person" é uma chave única, e essa "person" pode estar ligada a varias outras tabelas, mas ao fazer o post, ele sempre faz um "insert" no banco, enquanto se o registro ja existisse na tabela "person" ele deveria realizar um update na mesma, e um insert na tabela "supplier" ou outra qualquer que tem esse atributo.
Alguém poderia me ajudar? Se tiver alguma coisa errada com a pergunta, favor me informar e eu edito ela, não feche o tópico, estou precisando muito dessa ajuda.

Comment: O que acontece quando você tenta inserir um `"nome"` que já existe em sua base, da entidade "Person"?

Comment: Ocorre um erro no banco postgress porque esse nome já existe e ele é chave unica.

Comment: Pois é, deve ser o erro suplieralreadyexistswithnameexception. Neste caso não seria só tratar este caso, ao invés de lançar a exceção?

Comment: mas eu trato... pode observar que eu chamo o metodo procurando por nome, se existir eu seto esse id de person em supplier

Comment: Quando eu falei em tratar seria para o caso de não lançar a exceção . E sim fazer o update. Que é o que deseja…

Comment: mas quando dou o save, automaticamente o hibernate faz um insert

Comment: Certo, você faz o update e logo em seguida faz o return. Para o fluxo de save não ser executado.